# Video Streaming Issue

Tags: android, android-video-player

I want to play video in my application which is stored on the server.

I have checked a lot of post but i am unable to play the same in my application. Please help me to do the same.

Here is my code.

```
package com.example.videoStreaming;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    /**
     * TODO: Set the path variable to a streaming video URL or a local media
     * file path.
     */
    private String path = "http://www.pocketjourney.com/downloads/pj/video/famous.3gp";
    private VideoView mVideoView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view);

        if (path == "") {
            // Tell the user to provide a media file URL/path.
            Toast.makeText(
                    MainActivity.this,
                    "Please edit VideoViewDemo Activity, and set path"
                            + " variable to your media file URL/path",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else {

            /*
             * Alternatively,for streaming media you can use
             * mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(URLstring));
             */
            mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("http://www.pocketjourney.com/downloads/pj/video/famous.3gp"));
            mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
            mVideoView.requestFocus();

        }
    }
}
```

Here is the xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <VideoView 
        android:id="@+id/surface_view" 
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="240dp"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Please dont down my vote. If anybody who understands or can help Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: What happens when you try to play it?

Comment: No response Simply the screen shows blank ( with a black Surface view)

Comment: I caught my mistake. I forget to write mvideoview.start()

Now i have one problem It is very very very slow. Is it the right way to strem the videos???

Comment: It certainly is a standard way. Can you open the same stream in your device's browser? How does that compare?